# как функцию запуска дочернего процесса "заменить" СИ кодом

Tags: linux, c, ip

Вот такой "системный" код, хочу заменить на "СИ" код

```
 system("ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000 ");
```

Как это сделать ???

Comment: Посмотреть в исходном коде утилиты `ip` какой код она выполняет при получении такой команды.

Comment: Это не системный вызов, это функция запуска дочернего процесса

Comment: Отложить это занятие лучше.. там очень много телодвижений. Или смотреть исходники `ip`, но все основное не в нем, а в библиотеках. Так-же смотреть примеры http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html например

Answer (score 3):

Используйте сокеты NETLINK, их как раз и использует утилита `ip`.

В Linux настройка сети выполняется через сокеты NETLINK, которые представляют собой специальное семейство сокетов для связи ядра и пользовательской среды. Чтобы быть более точным, он настроен по протоколу NETLINK_ROUTE через сокет NETLINK.

Создавать примерно так:

```
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, 0)
или
socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE)
```

`C` код любых операций с NETLINK объемный, поэтому дам ссылки на примеры:

- https://github.com/lalten/libsocketcan
- http://maz-programmersdiary.blogspot.com/2011/09/netlink-sockets.html
- http://olegkutkov.me/2018/02/14/monitoring-linux-networking-state-using-netlink/
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html

Поскольку функционал связан с ядром системы, то есть некоторое различие в используемых структурах (и их размерах) в зависимости от версии ядра.

Comment: по правде говоря прекрасный ответ, но я не столь хорош в этом деле и совсем ни черта не понял ((((((

Comment: увы но NETLINK не поднимает интерфейс :(

Comment: так не может быть, проверяйте в дебагере на каком месте и какая ошибка на сокете.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы действительно хотите "подстрочник" для

> system("ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000 ");

то он выглядит приблизительно так:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

pid_t pid;
int wstatus;
char *args[] = {"ip", "link", "set", "can0", "type", "can", "bitrate", "125000", NULL};
int rc;

pid = fork();
if (pid != 0) {
    // Мы в родительском процессе - ждём завершения дочернего
    waitpid(pid, int &wstatus, 0);
    printf("Процесс ip завершон со статусом %x\n", wstatus);
} else {
    // Мы в дочернем процессе - запускаем утилиту ip
    execvp("ip", args);
    printf("Если мы оказались здесь - функция execvp завершилась ошибкой %d\n", rc);

}
```

Только я не компилировал - могут быть опечатки...